# Upgrading to a bigger SSD without loosing my dual boot?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, grub

I have installed a dual boot Windows 10/Kali Linux with grub on a 250 GB SSD. I have been happy with it for a while, but now I'm starting to run low on space. I would like to upgrade to a bigger SSD (500 GB, or maybe 1TB if I get the money), so I can extend my windows partition, and extend my Linux partition a bit too.

The thing is, I'm not so familiar about how grub works, how UEFI works, etc... And I wouldn't want to break everything and have to reinstall.

Currently, my disk looks like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi4Yk.png)

I have an internal hard disk to USB 3.0 adapter.

What I want to know is: if I buy a bigger disk, make a bit-by-bit copy of my current disk to the new one, will I be able to just move my Linux partition to the right within the unused space, and extend my windows partition? Will that cause trouble with grub, or boot in general?

Comment: @Cris Thank you, but... I know how to make a copy of my disk to the new one. That wasn't my question. My question is, once the copy is done, can I move my Linux partition to extend the windows one without causing issues with grub or UEFI?

Comment: @Cris, Alpha's question is about moving the Linux partition **after** cloning the HD, so that it's gonna be possible to increase Windows partition.

Comment: I usually use `gparted` on a live boot disc to make such changes, then `boot-repair` to sort out any boot issues, and I have found both programs reliable. I use Ubuntu, which is also a Debian derivative, and the live boot disc has both programs pre-installed, so the same may well be true of a Kali disc: if not, use an Ubuntu disc. Provided that you are careful not to overwrite the original SSD in any way, you will have this as a fall-back if anything goes wrong with the repositioning. It will be a good idea to check that the cloned disc boots before making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cloning the SSD it's possible to move the partition using a [professional partition tool](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/move-partition-windows-10.html).
I've never done this procedure myself and I can't be sure the dual boot won't be affected by the change in the partition, but I think you're safe to try since you're gonna have the original SSD to **rollback** the attempt if the dual boot is messed up.
Please, note that you should **test this solution properly** before doing anything to the original SSD.

Comment: Oh yeah, I completely forgot that the original disk would be unharmed, haha... @AFH advised running boot-repair if I encounter any error too. But since the original disk is untouched I can just try it without risking to lose all my data. Thanks!